# Get a specific value from a cell

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Below is my df.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame ({
    'IP':['10.140.34.210;0.0.0.0','0.0.0.0;0.0.0.0;10.0.1.87;0.0.0.0;0.0.0.0','0.0.0.0;172.31.48.174',
    '10.140.67.244;0.0.0.0', '1.1.1.1','3.3.3.3'],
    
    })

print(df)

                                          IP
0                      10.140.34.210;0.0.0.0
1  0.0.0.0;0.0.0.0;10.0.1.87;0.0.0.0;0.0.0.0
2                      0.0.0.0;172.31.48.174
3                      10.140.67.244;0.0.0.0
4                                    1.1.1.1
5                                    3.3.3.3
```

What I would like to achieve is to keep in the **IP** column just the correct IP address without any 0.0.0.0. This is the expected output.

```
                             IP
0                      10.140.34.210
1                      10.0.1.87
2                      172.31.48.174
3                      10.140.67.244
4                      1.1.1.1
5                      3.3.3.3
```

I tried with split but it doesn't do the job.

```
df = df['IP'].str.split(';',expand=True)
print(df)

             0              1          2        3        4
0  10.140.34.210        0.0.0.0       None     None     None
1        0.0.0.0        0.0.0.0  10.0.1.87  0.0.0.0  0.0.0.0
2        0.0.0.0  172.31.48.174       None     None     None
3  10.140.67.244        0.0.0.0       None     None     None
4        1.1.1.1           None       None     None     None
5        3.3.3.3           None       None     None     None
```

Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If thats the only exceptional case you need to get rid of, use `replace` with regex:

```
print(df["IP"].replace(";?0\.0\.0\.0;?","", regex=True))

0    10.140.34.210
1        10.0.1.87
2    172.31.48.174
3    10.140.67.244
4          1.1.1.1
5          3.3.3.3
Name: IP, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df[~df.IP.str.contains("0.0.0.0")]
    IP
4   1.1.1.1
5   3.3.3.3
```